# select only when different value

Tags: mysql

I have this column: name and price. I don't really know how or why in mysql database there are few line that are double record exactly from the previous line.

how to select all records but show only one of the records if the record is double with a line in front or behind it?

For example I have this records:

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book | 5 |
| 2 | lamp | 7 |
| 3 | lamp | 7 |
| 4 | book | 5 |
| 5 | book | 5 |

the result I want is:

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book | 5 |
| 2 | lamp | 7 |
| 4 | book | 5 |

Comment: More information required, please add your code , table definition, sample data , current output and expected output as text to the question. As things stand duplicate output is as it should be.

Comment: So you want the first occurrence of each change of name?

Comment: Apart from the id in your result name and price are the same for book - I am a bit baffled why you would want this.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude rows that match the previous `name`, there are several ways like the following.

Case 1:
If you use MySQL8, you can use the [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) function.

```sql
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.price FROM (
  SELECT t2.id,t2.name,t2.price,
    LAG(t2.name) OVER(ORDER BY t2.id) prev
  FROM mytable t2
) t1
WHERE t1.prev IS NULL OR t1.name<>t1.prev
ORDER BY 1
```

Case 2:
If the `id`s are continuous without any steps, you will get the expected result by comparing `name` and the previous `id` by JOIN.

```sql
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.price FROM mytable t1
  LEFT JOIN mytable t2
  ON t1.name=t2.name AND
     t1.id=t2.id-1
WHERE t1.id=1 OR t2.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

Case 3:
If the `id`s are not continuous, there is a way to get the maximum `id` that does not exceed the other `id`.

```sql
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.price FROM mytable t1
  LEFT JOIN mytable t2
  ON t1.name=t2.name AND
     t1.id=(SELECT MAX(t3.id) FROM mytable t3 WHERE t3.id<t2.id)
WHERE t1.id=1 OR t2.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8YfFCrdg2yik5Y4MxbtMp/1)

Comment: could you please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66729924/mysql-remove-duplicate-data-if-sequential

Answer (score 0):

`Select distinct` is not an option here as id column is always unique. I guess this will work for you:

```
select min(id), name, price from table_name group by name, price
```

Comment: almost, but with this query it only get id 1 and 2. I need the id 4 also