# mysql remove duplicate data if sequential

Tags: mysql

I have previously made a question here [select only when different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66525787/select-only-when-different-value) and it has been answered.
Now my question is how to remove double data so that the usual select query can produce the desired data

For example I have this records:

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book | 5 |
| 2 | lamp | 7 |
| 3 | lamp | 7 |
| 4 | book | 5 |
| 5 | book | 5 |

the result I want is:

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book | 5 |
| 2 | lamp | 7 |
| 4 | book | 5 |

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried and explain, in detail, what the problem is with it (error messages, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: How is this question different than your previous one?

Comment: Your sample data this time is exactly the same as the previcious one. Is it really correct?